# We are facing error while training the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, module, conv-neural-network

**Project Description :**
This is a code for Sign language detection
We are using following libraries

```
from keras.models import Sequential
```

**This is the Code**
This block of code is of training model of our project and we are getting error while training the model

```
classifier.fit(
        training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=12841,
        epochs=5,
        validation_data=test_set,
        validation_steps=4268)
```

**Error which we are facing....**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/nagar/Desktop/Sign-Language-to-Text-master/train.py", line 66, in <module>
    classifier.fit(
  File "C:\Users\nagar\Desktop\Sign-Language-to-Text-master\Virtual-Env\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\nagar\Desktop\Sign-Language-to-Text-master\Virtual-Env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 52, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "c:/Users/nagar/Desktop/Sign-Language-to-Text-master/train.py", 
line 66, in <module>
      classifier.fit(
    File "C:\Users\nagar\Desktop\Sign-Language-to-Text-master\Virtual-Env\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\nagar\Desktop\Sign-Language-to-Text-master\Virtual-Env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1650, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "C:\Users\nagar\Desktop\Sign-Language-to-Text-master\Virtual-Env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1249, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\nagar\Desktop\Sign-Language-to-Text-master\Virtual-Env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1233, in step_function      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))    
    File "C:\Users\nagar\Desktop\Sign-Language-to-Text-master\Virtual-Env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1222, in run_step     
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\nagar\Desktop\Sign-Language-to-Text-master\Virtual-Env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1024, in train_step   
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\nagar\Desktop\Sign-Language-to-Text-master\Virtual-Env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1082, in compute_loss 
      return self.compiled_loss(
    File "C:\Users\nagar\Desktop\Sign-Language-to-Text-master\Virtual-Env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__ 
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "C:\Users\nagar\Desktop\Sign-Language-to-Text-master\Virtual-Env\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 152, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "C:\Users\nagar\Desktop\Sign-Language-to-Text-master\Virtual-Env\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 284, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\nagar\Desktop\Sign-Language-to-Text-master\Virtual-Env\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 2004, in categorical_crossentropy
      return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    File "C:\Users\nagar\Desktop\Sign-Language-to-Text-master\Virtual-Env\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5538, in categorical_crossentropy
      return tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
Node: 'categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits'       
logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[10,27] labels_size=[10,29]
         [[{{node categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1784]
2022-12-16 19:17:46.716640: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:108] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: 
FAILED_PRECONDITION: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
         [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
```

Please if any one knows to resolve the error can help.

We tried to google the error but we are able to find the exact solution for the problem which we are facing

Comment: you need to look at the `training_set` data, and for anyone to debug, we need reproducible code. Note: noticed that you are using a prior version of Keras where it was standalone now it's part of TensorFlow. In any way, back end version did not create this error.

Comment: ```logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[10,27] labels_size=[10,29]``` seems pretty clear to me as error message

Comment: @NagarjunA, It seems like there are 29 classes, but you have passed 27 units in the output layer.  Please share the model so that we can provide better assistance. Thank you!